# active admin, cannot create nested resource at the same time as the parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems, activeadmin

In my app, `Invoice` has_many `Item`. So in my active admin UI, I want to be able to create a invoice, and at the same time create its items.

But I can only add `items` after the `invoice` is created using the `Edit Invoice` button in active admin. Trying to create them together will not direct me anywhere from the `New Invoice` page. And there aren't any errors shown. Could someone help me out on this?

I have the following form structure in my `app/admin/invoice.rb`

```
permit_params :paid, :due, :customer_id,
              items_attributes: [:price, :description, :invoice_id, :purchased_product_id]

form multipart: true do |f|
  f.inputs do
    input :customer
    input :due
    input :paid, as: :radio
  end
  f.inputs "Items" do
    f.has_many :items do |item|
      item.input :price
      item.input :description
      item.input :purchased_product
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```

I have added the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in my `Invoice` model as follow:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true

  validates :customer, presence: true
```

I am using Rails 4, and `activeadmin '~> 1.0.0.pre1'`

Comment: what if you add `:id` to `items_attributes`?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, didn't work either :( Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to deal with my validations in my `Item` model. I had the following validation rule in my `Item` model class

```
validates :price, :invoice, presence: true
```

This says that in order to create an `item`, it has to have an `invoice` connected. But since in the creation process of the `invoice` and its contained `items`, `invoice` is yet saved to database. The `items` can't find an `invoice` to connect to yet, and the validation failed.

The problem is solved by removing the presence validation of `invoice`, to

```
validates :price, presence: true
```